# Find values in char array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a char array and the text actually looks like XML:

```xml
<root>
<number>1</number>
<counter>2</counter>
<lastNumber>3</lastNumber>
</root>
```

I need to get these values  and store them to variables so I can work with them.

Any idea how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Use an xml library?

Comment: That doesn't look like a char array at all, it looks a lot like _XML_...

Comment: why not just use regexp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use TinyXML, to parse the file. http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/
Its a open source library to parse XML files in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You should formulate a better question, but the general idea is clear and so I suggest to use a library such as `boost::spirit` or, if you can arrange your data in a different way, you can use `boost::config` which is probably a much simpler approach and [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175502/how-to-parse-ini-file-with-boost) .

Comment: `boost::spirit` for writing yet another xml parser? No way, unless you are doing homework. There are bunch of production-ready xml parsers to use, so leave `boost::spirit` for really new languages.

Comment: @hate-engine all you can say right now it's that the OP needs to parse a file, no reference about any XML specific schema or DTD of any kind, in this case, generic case, boost::spirit is the only way to go, also there are many case where the word XML it's not enough, there are many schemas for XML.