# Python ConfigParser to C++

Tags: python, c++, c, ini, configparser

I am working with a python program that outputs a file via ConfigParser. I am writing a program in c/c++ that needs access to these config files. Some of the options are multi-line so I can not simply scan the file for "x = y" and strip the "x = " part out.

Is there a ready made solution through a c/c++ library that will allow me to easily read the ConfigParser's files.

I would like a lean solution, possibly in a GPL or similar licence so I can just include it with my code for a complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style of file ConfigParser outputs is known as a 'ini file'. This should help you searches.

[How to parse ini file with Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175502/how-to-parse-ini-file-with-boost)

To get you started.

Comment: You know you have been on Linux a long time when your forget what an *.ini file looks like LOL. I ended up using inih from google code. Very small c file.