# linker can not find symbols but they're there?

Tags: c++11, linker, symbols

Trying to compile this [cfgparser example](http://cfgparser.sourceforge.net/?page=example#server).

```
$ g++ example.cc -lcfgparser
: In function `main':
example.cc:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `ConfigParser_t::readFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
example.cc:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) const'
example.cc:(.text+0x2d9): undefined reference to `ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int*) const'
example.cc:(.text+0x43c): undefined reference to `ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double*) const'
example.cc:(.text+0x5b1): undefined reference to `ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool*) const'
example.cc:(.text+0x78c): undefined reference to `ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >*) const'
example.cc:(.text+0xa15): undefined reference to `ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) const'
example.cc:(.text+0xba2): undefined reference to `ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) const'
example.cc:(.text+0xd15): undefined reference to `ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) const'
example.cc:(.text+0xe7f): undefined reference to `ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit statu
```

But clearly those symbols are there:

```
$ nm -gC /usr/lib/libcfgparser.so
000000000003710 T ConfigParser_t::readFile(std::string const&)
0000000000004880 T ConfigParser_t::ConfigParser_t(std::string const&)
00000000000024c0 T ConfigParser_t::ConfigParser_t()
0000000000004ad0 T ConfigParser_t::ConfigParser_t(std::string const&)
00000000000024a0 T ConfigParser_t::ConfigParser_t()
0000000000004d20 T ConfigParser_t::getOptions(std::string const&) const
00000000000028d0 T ConfigParser_t::getSections() const
0000000000002ff0 T ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::string, std::string, bool*) const
0000000000002de0 T ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::string, std::string, double*) const
0000000000002bd0 T ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::string, std::string, int*) const
00000000000027d0 T ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::string, std::string, std::string*) const
0000000000003500 T ConfigParser_t::getValue(std::string, std::string, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >*) const
```

Unlike other similar problems on SO, this is NOT about linking order, as there is only one object file being linked. Anything I'm missing??

Comment: My guess is, the two modules are built in such a way that `std::string` means different things to them. Linked with different flavors of C++ runtime library, perhaps?

Comment: The problem can be that you're including `stdio.h` and not `cstdio` if you copied the example code. That would match broken linkage on char-related stuff. Other things to check: was your `libcfgparser.so` built with `std::string` supporting `wchar_t` ?

Comment: I had the same problem ensure for ABI compatibility ensure the -m32/-m64 matches for you library/executable builds.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for sharing the command line you used for nm.  I had never heard of this tool, and finding this method of diagnosing my (what turned out for me to be a namespace) problem saved me hours.  Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> But clearly those symbols are there:

Clearly, they're not. Take a closer look and you will see that
there are no matches between the signatures reported by your
linker as undefined and those reported from the library by
`nm`.

The Standard header `<string>` defines `std::string` as typedef for:

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>
```

The GCC implementation of `<string>`, as of the [cxx11 ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility) (GCC 4.7.0)
defines `std::string` as a typedef for:

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>
```

The `std::__cxx11` name space encloses types whose binary implementations are
compliant with the cxx11 ABI.

That type definition means that C++ translation unit that includes the Standard header `<string>` won't
compile, with GCC >= 4.7, into object code containing a symbol that demangles as `std::string`.

If a binary - like your `libcfgparser.so` - contains a symbol that demangles as `std::string`, then 
whatever that symbol might have referred to in the sources from which it was built, *it does not refer to* `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`,
and cannot be linked with other binaries that were compiled with that definition of `std::string`.

Your `libcfgparser.so` is the one installed by `libcfgparser0_1.1.2_amd64.deb` from the
[cfgparser Sourceforce project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cfgparser/files/libcfgparser/)
(which was last updated three years ago). I guess this from that the fact that I 
get your linkage error with same `example.cc` program linked against the library that is installed by that package.

The explanation for the error is revealed by:

```
/usr/lib$ strings -a libcfgparser.so | grep "GCC: ("
GCC: (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2
...
```

which tells us that this library was built with GCC 4.3.2 - pre the cxx11 ABI.

The `std::string` that appears in your `nm` output is a pre-cxx11 demangling abbreviation
of `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`.

This `libcfgparser.so` is ABI-incompatible with your current GCC, so you
can't link it with programs that you build with that compiler. What you can do is 
build `libcfgparser` from the source package, `libcfgparser-1.1.2.tar.bz2`,
with your current compiler and then link your programs with the library you have
built yourself.

That works, but not effortlessly. First you'll need to fix the broken
and antiquated autotooling of the source package to create a working `./configure`
script.

Which doesn't give a reassuring impression of the proficiency of the package maintainer. 
Plus the source code of the package, copyright 2008, is of amateur quality. If
what you are after is a C++ parser for INI-style files, then [`boost::property_tree::ini_parser`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) would be the
goto solution. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6176389/1362568)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very helpful and educational. I was guessing the similar reason but I can't conclude probably because "The `std::string` that appears in your `nm` output is a pre-cxx11 demangling **abbreviation** of `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>` -- I don't how to de-abbreviate `std::string` correctly.

Comment: Also using `boost::property_tree::ini_parser` is a good call.

Comment: @qweruiop You're welcome. The `std::string` (demangled) = `Ss` (mangled) was a *hardcoded* abbreviation in the pre-cxx11 GCC name-mangling. No logic to it but convenience. But what you can count on is that symbols within binaries, whether mangled or demangled, that are *different* are *different to the linker*, 'cos they're what the linker sees.