# Cannot open ini file with read_ini function in boost library

Tags: c++, boost, ini

Follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175502/how-to-parse-ini-file-with-boost), I'm trying to read an ini file.

```
try {
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini("profiles.ini", pt);
    std::cout << pt.get<std::string>("Session1.Value1") << std::endl;
}
catch(const boost::property_tree::ptree_error &e)
{
     cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

But I'm get this error.

[image]

Another question, Can I read an ini file with a path with boost lib?

Answer (score 0):

this probably `profiles.ini` is not in your working directory, or current account does not have permission to access it.

Comment: I put exe and ini file in a same folder (Debug). How can I set this folder to "working"?

Comment: if you run your app using Terminal(or Cmd on Windows) you can change working directory by using `cd your_working_dir` before issue run your app command